# Difference between two values from the same column

Tags: sql-server

I need the difference between Hours on ‘Today’ (200) and ‘Today-4’ (220)  in the field Difference (-20.00). How someone help me build a query for this?

```
Today        Date      Hours    Difference
10/29/2014  11/15/2014  220  
10/30/2014  11/15/2014  220  
10/31/2014  11/15/2014  200  
11/1/2014   11/15/2014  200  
11/2/2014   11/15/2014  200     -20.00
```

Comment: Is it always today minus 4?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Also, are these the only columns available, or do you have other columns in the table?

Comment: what basis you need find difference?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE Time1 int;
DECLARE Time2 int;
DECLARE Result int;

SET Time1 = (SELECT Hours From TBL_NAME WHERE Today = '10/29/2014')
SET Time2 = (SELECT Hours From TBL_NAME WHERE Today = '11/2/2014')
SET Result = Time1 - Time2;

UPDATE TBL_NAME SET Difference = Result WHERE Today = 'Your Field Value'
```

Comment: I just simplified a complicated query. So here is what I am trying to get:

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Difference=((SELECT HOURS FROM TABLE WHERE TODAY='10/29/2014)'
-(SELECT HOURS FROM TABLE WHERE TODAY='11/2/2014'))
WHERE TODAY = '11/2/2014'
```